# CoreLocation on macOS always return location services disabled

Tags: swift, macos, core-location, macos-high-sierra, location-services

I'm stuck on using CoreLocation on macOS High Sierra.

I need to get current user location but this code:

```
if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .restricted:
            print("You don't have permission to use Location Services.")
        case .denied:
            print("You denied permission to use Location Services, please enable it in Preferences.")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Non determinati")
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        default: ()
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Location services disabled")
    }
```

always print "Location services disabled".

locationManager is a class property initialized at instance creation.

Even trying to use a MapView with `showUserLocation = true` doesn't work.
In my Mac settings I have Location Services enabled but my app doesn't show on list (maybe because it has never requested user location access).

I already setted "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" on my app Info.plist file
Anyone knows how to ask correctly for user location? I'm currently running my app directly from XCode.

Comment: Use the CLLocationManagerDelegate methods.

Comment: Check your app's signing/provisioning status.

Comment: did you manage to get a solution for this? I am also stuck. If you have a solution please post as an answer so that it will help others. Thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

hgj

in your info.plist add this `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` , type `String` and in value write why are you asking for location

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem, locationServicesEnabled() keeps returning false

Comment: try using it in a Device, not on simulator

Comment: it's a macOS app, it doesn't have simulator

Answer (score 0):

check if the you have turned on AppSandbox in capabilities.
Turn it off and try again.
This fixed the problem for me.